# php filter API on 2-dimensional array

Tags: php, validation

I have 2-dimensional GET parameters like request?a[b]=2

I would like to use the php input filter API (http://www.php.net/filter) but cannot find a reasonable way to work on the input a[b].

```
filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'a'); // true
```

but

```
filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'a[b]'); // false
```

is there a way to instruct this API to work with 2-dim input parameters ?

Thank you for your help

Jerome

Comment: Why not use the $_GET superglobal?

Comment: @afuzzyllama: Because it does not tell you if the variable was set by the request *or* by code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a[b]` is not a variable name. You can only use `filter_has_var` with a correct variable name. The variable name for your parameter is `a` regardless if it is an array or a string.

So you must first check if the get input contains the a parameter and then check it's contents.

```
$hasVar   = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'a');
$hasArray = $hasVar && is_array($_GET['a']);
```

Hope this helps.